# How to make contents having equal space (width & hight) to resize upon changing of window size in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid, viewbox

I have the following code of XAML in WPF. This generates the grid with equal size of columns & rows (as shown in figure 1.)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

     <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Text="A" Background="Green"/>
     <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Text="AB" Background="Red"/>
     <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"  Text="ABC" Background="Blue"/>
     <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3"  Text="ABCD" Background="Yellow"/>
</Grid>
```

Figure 1.

[image: Figure 1.]

But when I put this grid in a viewbox (like the code below), the rows & column remains no more equally in size (as shown in figure 2.).

```
<Viewbox  Stretch="Uniform">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Text="A" Background="Green"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Text="AB" Background="Red"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"  Text="ABC" Background="Blue"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3"  Text="ABCD" Background="Yellow"/>

    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Figure 2.

[image: Figure 2.]

How can I make this grid with equal size of rows & column inside a viewbox?

Comment: why viewbox ? still

Comment: because I want to resize my contents upon changing widows size.

Comment: it should work as expected with *, have you tried removing viewbox, if not sorry I am still not able to understand your requiremtn

Comment: @Muds, I want the grid size as in figure 1, (not as in Figure 2) as well as contents to be resized on changing window size as in Figure 2 (not in Figure 1 because of no viewbox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enforce size-sharing like this:

```
<Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
        <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
        <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
        <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's the behavior of `ViewBox`

Taken from internet

> The ViewBox is a very useful control in WPF. If does nothing more than
>   scale to fit the content to the available size. It does not resize the
>   content, but it transforms it.

why use viewbox when you don't want this, try another control.

Comment: I want to resize my contents inside grid and also want to remain them in equal space.

Comment: what do you mean exactly ? please change your question to indicate what you want

Comment: I believe he wants the size of the text to scale down to fit within the cells.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a Grid try using a UniformGrid:

```
<Viewbox  Stretch="Uniform">
    <UniformGrid Rows="4" Columns="4">
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Text="A" Background="Green"/>
        <TextBlock />
        <TextBlock />
        <TextBlock />

        <TextBlock />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Text="AB" Background="Red"/>
        <TextBlock />
        <TextBlock />

        <TextBlock />
        <TextBlock />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"  Text="ABC" Background="Blue"/>
        <TextBlock />

        <TextBlock />
        <TextBlock />
        <TextBlock />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3"  Text="ABCD" Background="Yellow"/>
        </UniformGrid>
</Viewbox>
```

Just make sure you set Rows And Columns, and instead of saying which row/column each child element is, you just enter them in order.

Comment: Your answer solves my problem, but we have to define some extra "TextBlock" to make them as per required. Thank you very much. Anyhow, @H.B.'s answer gives me the perfectly working solution.